# How to fetch color hex codes from database into scss files in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am using React JS and Sass for frontend. Aim is to customize the pages i.e., to fetch the color values from database into scss files. I have a constants scss file which has all color variables with hex codes. I want to fetch these color values from the database. How can we achieve this?

_constants.scss

```
$background: #e6e6e6;
$accent: #abe2fb;
$accentDark: #4c83fa;
$accentHover: #77a1fd;
$backgroundDark: #999999;
$errorDark: #cc0000;
$errorLight:  #ffe6e6;
```

Comment: I'd use css variables and fetch them from your API and then set them in a style take for `root`

Comment: Should this style setting be done in js file? Is there any way to pass it to scss file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not directly.

The `_constants.scss` is a static file which I assume isn't going to be updated on every request.

Why you store the color values in the db? Is it different by each individual user? If this is the case, I suggest you to create an API to fetch this and inject to React at runtime.

If you're just building an application that support different themes, then you're better of with generating 2 `_constants.scss` (e.g. `darkmode.scss` & `lightmode.scss`), and you just store the theme name in the db. In this case, you'd can just inject different stylesheet depending on the selected theme.

Comment: Yes, it is a customizable widget so colors can be different for each user. Can you provide more information about injecting to React at runtime? Thanks

Comment: @Vid - You can dynamically style the React component using inline style https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style . So your need a backend API that can return you the styles, then you can inject it to your code.

You didn't mentioned what backend tech stack you're using (e.g Express.js? Rails? php?), so can't provide much info.

Comment: Backend is Express.js. Can backend generate this constants.scss file? The thing is, we have done all the styling using sass for all components and now shifting to inline styles would be a lot of work.

Comment: You could generate the scss file dynamically on each request (using fs module), but that wont work either, because browser only understand css. To compile scss into css, you'll need another tool (webpack, postcss, etc).

Comment: So it's not practical to dynamically generate the scss file on each request.

Comment: What about just loading file once when the app starts using webpack? I am sorry, I don't have much knowledge about webpack

Comment: Well, that would means on application starts, it's going to generate all the scss for all users and compiles them with webpack. And on each request, you would have to detect which css to load. Also, you'd need to have webpack installed on your production server! When user update the values you need a way to regenerate those files. You could hack your way to that, but I don't recommends this at all.